# Laravel Livewire set dynamic value to x-admin.forms.label

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to create dynamic variable **$isRequired** that will change based on the value from other parts of the form.

```
 <x-admin.forms.label value="Tax rate %" required="{{$isRequired}}"  hint-content="" hint-title=""/>
```

The x-admin does not seem to accept variables.

This is the class where the variable is set:

```
use Livewire\Component;

class MyForm extends Component
{

 public $isRequired = true;

}
```

Comment: You have it defined on the livewire component, but does the `resources/views/components/admin/forms/label` have  a `required` property?

Comment: @rits hi. thank you for your reply. i am not sure what you mean by required property

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#passing-data-to-components
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#data-properties-attributes